# Spark Dataframe Arraytype columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to create a new column on a dataframe, which is the result of applying a function to an arraytype column.

Something like this:

```
df = df.withColumn("max_$colname", max(col(colname)))
```

where each row of the column holds an array of values?

The functions in spark.sql.function appear to work on a column basis only.

Comment: what kind of function you want to apply?

Comment: Any of the standard summary statistics: min, max, count, mean, variance, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply user defined functions on the array column.

1.DataFrame

```
+------------------+
|               arr|
+------------------+
|   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
|[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|
+------------------+
```

2.Creating UDF

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def max(arr: TraversableOnce[Int])=arr.toList.max
val maxUDF=udf(max(_:Traversable[Int]))
```

3.Applying UDF in query

```
df.withColumn("arrMax",maxUDF(df("arr"))).show
```

4.Result

```
+------------------+------+
|               arr|arrMax|
+------------------+------+
|   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|     5|
|[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|     9|
+------------------+------+
```

Comment: I wrote code to find max from array. Similar way you can write logic to do any operation on array.